# SQL: Calculate bitrate

Tags: mysql, sql, bitrate

I have a column with bytes, and another with milliseconds. And I must calculate average bitrate in bits per second.

I'm doing this:

```
SELECT AVG(Bytes*8)/AVG(Milliseconds/1000)
FROM Tracks
```

Apparently it is wrong. I'm using an app with exercises

I have this result

254492.61

And should be

254400.25

Comment: And ?? What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only want one average calculation

```
SELECT AVG((Bytes*8.0)/(Milliseconds/1000.0))
FROM Tracks
```

and you may want to increase precision to decimals which is why 8.0 and 1000.0 are used above. Remove if unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write this as:

```
SELECT SUM(Bytes*8) / SUM(Milliseconds/1000)
FROM Tracks
```

This is equivalent to your query, though -- assuming that the values are never `NULL`.

Perhaps they mean the average of averages:

```
SELECT AVG(Bytes * 8 / (Milliseconds / 1000))
FROM Tracks;
```

I would not describe this as the average bits per second, however.